# Query for column changes when object of another column is the same

Tags: sql

Purpose: I need to query for the ITEM number and VALUE where the VALUE is different for the same ITEM number.

TABLE DATA:

The Table containt columns: ITEMS, TYPE and VALUE

ITEM CL1 contains 6 rows, 4 rows have TYPE = P, 2 rows are TYPE = K, All 6 rows have VALUE = 10.

ITEM CL2 contains 6 rows, 4 rows have TYPE = P and all have a VALUE = 1, 2 rows are TYPE = K and both have VALUE = 9

ITEM CL3 contains 6 rows, 4 rows have TYPE = P and 3 rows have a VALUE = 20 and 1 row VALUE = 3, 2 rows are TYPE = K and both have VALUE = 15

ITEM CL4 contains 8 rows, 6 rows have TYPE = P and all have a VALUE = 18 , 2 rows are TYPE = K and 1 row has a VALUE = 11 and the other row has a VALUE = 7

Desired Results: ITEM CL1 should not return as part of the query results, however, ITEM CL2, ITEM CL3 and ITEM CL4 should.

I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: Please add more sample data and also add expected output in a table form for the sample data. Also mention the database you are working on

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always represent sample data and desired output in this format

```
ITEMS  TYPE  VALUE
 CL1    P     10
 CL1    K     10
 CL2    P     1
 CL3    P     1
 CL4    K     9
 CL4    K     9
```

Lets Assume table name is TableA

As you have mentioned

> I need to query for the ITEM number and VALUE where the VALUE is
>   different for the same ITEM number.

We need to know all item numbers which have more than one value so we use [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) function

```
SELECT Items FROM TableA GROUP BY Items HAVING COUNT(Value)>1
```

As you don't want Item CL1  in your result set you should add a [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause

```
WHERE Items!= 'CL1'
```

Hence you query is

```
SELECT Items, Type, Value
FROM TableA
WHERE Items!= 'CL1'
AND Items IN (SELECT Items FROM TableA GROUP BY Items HAVING COUNT(Value)>1)
```